# AKS keep calling "Create or Update Load Balancer" operation and I want to stop it

Tags: azure, kubernetes, load-balancing

On Azure:
I have an AKS cluster and a load abalancer. 
I am keep getting an operation "Create or Update Load Balancer" in the load balancer log, 
every 1-2 minutes. What can cause this log, and can I stop this operation from occuring ? 
[image: azure load balancer log]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click the log and look at the change history which is a preview version, then you can see more details about the log like this:

[image]

These logs are written by the reason that all you change the services with the Load Balancer type.

And unfortunately, I'm afraid you cannot stop the logs. You can only create the AKS cluster and the agent pools and set some configurations, but do not include the log. All the settings for the Infrastructure of the AKS are not configurable to you. It's designed by Azure.